# How do I add images to a slide using PHPPowerPoint?

Tags: php, phppowerpoint

[PHPPowerPoint](http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/) is a great library, but it has no documentation. What is the proper syntax for adding images to a slide?

Comment: Have you downloaded the source code yet, they have a folder called `Test` which shows you how to do this in the `01simple.php` example

Answer (score 3):

```
$currentSlide = createTemplatedSlide($objPHPPowerPoint); 
// createTemplatedSlide is manual function in PHPpowerPoint

// create a drawing shape object
$shape1 = $currentSlide->createDrawingShape();
$shape1->setName("set name here");
$shape1->setDescription('Link Image');
$shape1->setPath('provide image path here');
$shape1->setWidth(45); // set width
$shape1->setHeight(45); // set height
$shape1->setOffsetX($offset_X); // distance from the left side of the slide
$shape1->setOffsetY($offset_Y); // distance from top of the slide
```

Answer (score 2):

Each graphical object is considered as a "shape". here is the way to insert an image into the slide:

```
// Create slide 1
$currentSlide = createTemplatedSlide($objPHPPowerPoint); 
        //Slide Content
    $shape = $currentSlide->createDrawingShape();
    $shape->setName('Part page');
    $shape->setDescription('Page');
    $shape->setPath('D:\wamp\www\Project\PPTResource\Part2\Image.jpg'); //This being the directory, wont be the same as mine.
    $shape->setOffsetX(10); //Default values on position of image
    $shape->setOffsetY(10);
    $shape->getShadow()->setVisible(true);
    $shape->getShadow()->setDirection(45);
    $shape->getShadow()->setDistance(10);
```